# Reactjs ajax Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and probably doing something wrong here but I keep getting a $ is undefined when making an ajax request.  Here is the class I am making the request from:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Projects.scss';
import Link from '../Link';
import Overlay from '../Overlay';

var Project = React.createClass({
  // Project detail class, commented out because it is big.
});

var Projects = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { data: [] };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.get('http://localhost:3000/api/posts').done(function(data) {
      this.setState({data: data});
    }.bind(this));
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Project data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }

});

export default Projects;
```

It's returning:
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined from componentDidMount()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.get implies that you are trying to use jQuery, you probably haven't actually loaded it.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  It threw me off when typing $ in console it was defined.  Thanks